# How can I get my game character to stay within the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics

I've been searching around and still couldnt find a fix to how to keep this moving object within the borders of my canvas. We tried to put an if statement into each arrow key movement functions, but that didnt seem to work completely. I'm not sure whether or not this is the right way to go about handling game movement since the image that we are moving is defined in the HTML and not defined as a variable in the javascript.

```js
var width = 80;
var height = 40;

function leftArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 17+'px';
  }
  
  

  function rightArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 25 +'px';
  }

  

  function upArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 17 + 'px';
  }

  function downArrowPressed() {

  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 17 + 'px';
  }

  function moveSelection(evt) {
      switch (evt.keyCode) {
          case 37:
          leftArrowPressed();
          break;
          case 39:
          rightArrowPressed();
          break;
          case 38:
          upArrowPressed();
          break;
          case 40:
          downArrowPressed();
          break;
          }
      };

function docReady()
{

window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 50;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});

canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
  var obj = document.getElementById("image1");
   // if object is too big ignore
  if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width){
      return;
  }        
  obj.setCoords();        
  // top-left  corner
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
      obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
      obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
  }
  // bot-right corner
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
      obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
      obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
  }
});
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: darkgrey;
outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
body {
overflow
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GridEXEMovement.js"></script>
    <title>Test Move Object</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dimRoom.css">
  </head>
  
  <body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="">
    <!-- uncomment this div when you want to implement the green desktop Div -->
    <nav>
        
      <ul>
      
      <li><button id="zeldaDeskTop">deskTop</button></li>
      <span>|</span>
      <li><button id="zeldaBrowser">browser</button></li>
      <span>|</span>
      <li><button id="zeldaExe">.exe</button></li>
      <span>|</span>
      <li><button id="zeldaGrid">grid</button></li>
     
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="screen">
    
    <div id="content"></div>
    <style>
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}


html {
  height: 100%;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
      body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

html {
  height: 100%;
}
#content{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:       linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent);
  height:100%;
  background-size:50px 50px;
}

.follow-me {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


         </style> 
  </div>
  <img id="image1" src="https://www.bigbluebubble.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/PixelDodggers_Classic8-bitExperience.png" style="position: absolute; right: 100; left:980; top:300; z-index: 2; margin:0;" height="50" width="50">
  <img id="DigitalCave" src="http://pixelartmaker.com/art/8fb5394537feede.png" style="position:absolute; left:560; top:146; z-index: 1;" height="30" width="40">
  <img id="DataNode" src="http://pixelart.studio/Gallery/Image/100b0c98-d22d-4ffc-868a-9862aad1da4a?type=png" style="position:absolute; left:360; top:544; z-index: 1;" height="30" width="40">
  <img id="Fire" src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/mt/science/flame-330.png" style="position:absolute; left:510; top:537; z-index: 1;" height="30" width="40">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dimRoom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check if element.style.top and element.style.left is at a certain value. Then set the value to 0 if too far left and the canvas width if too far right. Same thing obviously for up and down. I’ve never done it like this but it seems like a logical option to try.

Comment: We added an if statement to the javascript in the right and left buttons to check if the style.left is equal to the canvas width (50). The canvas width is correct and sets the boundary, but now when the left key is pressed the character automatically moves to the canvas width.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable for speed:

```
var yspeed = 17;
var xspeed = 25;
```

You made a mistake there by the way. You sideways speeds are different each way.

Sideways speed should be the same both ways `25px` each way.

If you canvas width is on `50px` then the player will move very quickly across the canvas with a speed of `17px` and `25px`.

Then check if the speed isn’t equal to zero

```
if (speed !== 0) { // you are moving your character
    // put your JavaScript you just created for wish and height checking here
}
```

Also in order to check if you’ve pressed your arrows return a Boolean when they have been used like this:

```
function leftArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - xspeed+'px';
return true;
  }



  function rightArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + xspeed +'px';
return true;
  }



  function upArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - yspeed + 'px';

return true;

  }

  function downArrowPressed() {

  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + yspeed + 'px';
  return true;
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: its saying the fabric in the canvas is not defined when i try to check the returns, but the character is moving

Comment: @Teqh have you got it to work yet? I don’t know what to do about the error. Do you mind sending the error message?

Comment: the movement itself works, i think i probably need to just redo the canvas

Answer (score 1):

I would make an x and y speed, and do something like this for the player:

```
player = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    xspeed: 0,
    yspeed: 0
};
```

Then I would do an if statement like this:

```
if (player.x < 0 || player.x > canvas.width) {
    player.x = 0;
    player.xspeed = 0;
}
if (player.y < 0 || player.y > canvas.height) {
    player.y = 0;
    player.yspeed = 0;
}
```

That should keep the player visible. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, for gravity, you could add 1 to yspeed each frame